# Cucumber undefined step reference in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have problem with Intellij 2019.2.4 Ultimate where I am unable to navigate from Cucumber feature file to glue code. Intellj is complaining of "Undefined Step Reference". Executing the cucumber test from console or via run configuration is however successfull.

Cucumber version 5.5.0
Junit version 4.13

Based on similary reported issues, this is what I have tried so far:

- Verified that both Cucumber for Java and Gherkin plugins are enabled
- Invalidate cache and restarted IDEA
- Verified that SubSteps plugin is not enabled and in conflict with Cucumber for Java plugin
- Reenable Cucumber for Java plugin

To illustrate my problem I have generated a simple project:

src/test/java/hellocucumber

```
package hellocucumber;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/hellocucumber"},
        glue={"hellocucumber"},
        monochrome = true
)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

my glue code

```
package hellocucumber;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @Given("today is Monday")
    public void today_is_Monday() {
        System.out.println("Today is monday");
    }
}
```

and my feature file:
src/test/resources/hellocucumber/test.feature

```
Feature: This is a test

  Scenario: Today is or is not Friday
    Given today is Monday
```

Intellij complain of missing glue code:

[image]

I am lost and would much appreciate some input. Thanks

**EDIT:**
Uploaded project[OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkkQjQvpQNm7geVRfvHmk6sQFTTABw?e=d6QYKs)

Also note, if I downgrade cucumber version from 5.5.0 to pre 5.x.x (e.g. 4.8.1) I am able to navigate from feature to glue!

Comment: Please zip and share the project  ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) using any file sharing service.

Comment: See edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This project works fine in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3, please consider [updating](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) if you are using the recent Cucumber version.

[image: 2019.3.3]

Comment: Had the exact same scenario and issue as OP and this answer is the only one that worked for me. Should be marked as the answer.